# In rails, how can I create a merged relation between two has_many :through relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have a set of Active Record models, setup like this:

```
Account
  has_many :account_groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :account_groups

Posts
  has_many :post_groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :post_groups
```

This is a security configuration, and I need to be able to query Posts that belong to a group that the Account has access to....so, I'd like to be able to say:

```
@account.posts
```

And get a filtered query of posts that belong to groups that overlap the groups the account has access to....but I can't seem to figure out the right syntax.

Help.

To clarify, the SQL I'm looking to generate would look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.* FROM accounts
    JOIN account_groups ON account_groups.account_id = accounts.id
    JOIN groups ON groups.id = account_groups.group_id
    JOIN post_groups ON post_groups.group_id = groups.id
    JOIN posts ON posts.id = post_groups.post_id
    WHERE accounts.id = 2
```

I'd really like it to be a named scope or relation and not just finder sql, too.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could get:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  def posts
    Post.includes(:post_groups => [:group => [:account_groups => :account]]).where('account_groups.account_id = ?',1)
  end
end
```

You could probably extract it to a scope, instead:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :post_groups

  scope :for_account, lambda {|account| joins(:post_groups => [:group => [:account_groups => :account]]).where('account_groups.account_id = ?',account.id)}
end
```

Both produce:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "post_groups" ON "post_groups"."post_id" = "posts"."id" INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "post_groups"."group_id" INNER JOIN "account_groups" ON "account_groups"."group_id" = "groups"."id" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "account_groups"."account_id" WHERE (account_groups.account_id = 1)
```

Both of these... require that PostGroup belongs_to :group and group has_many account_groups